# Изменение свойста из другого окна MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю MVVM, и всё было успешно, пока не наткнулся на сложную задачу.

Что есть:

1. окно `Main`
2. окно `Chat`, который связан с `ChatVM`

Что нужно сделать при нажатии на кнопку в `Main`:

1. поменять свойство в `ChatVM`
2. выполнить код, который требует экземпляр `Chat`

Что бы было понятнее:

`Chat` изначально имеет хук на сквозной клик, двигать его нельзя. Кнопка в `Main` должна поменять оформление `Chat` (сделать рамку) и убрать хук на сквозной клик.

Как всё это провернуть?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php

Comment: ChatVM положите в MainVM, тогда вы сможете изменить его свойство сверху